# Matlab: Interlace two arrays into one array

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to merge two arrays in Matlab like this

```
A = [1 2; 
     3 4]

B = [5 6;
     7 8]

C = [1 5;
     3 7;
     2 6;
     4 8]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the `:` operator:

```
C = [A(:) B(:)]
```